# Client gRPC connection with reconnect in C++?

Tags: c++, grpc

Is it possible to have a client channel that automatically reconnects?
I tried using `wait_for_ready(true)` on the context, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

I get this crash when I try to use a client channel with a lost connection:

```
E0519 12:56:40.239405883    9379 client_context.cc:119]      assertion failed: call_ == nullptr
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

My problem was attempting to re-use a context. Creating a new context for each attempt fixed the issue.